# Guide to upgrading loopback API core files and configuration to latest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I just ran a new scaffolding using `slc loopback` and then compared `server/server.js` and the server/ contents, and they are slightly different.

My main goal is to re-enable the loopback explorer and get up to date with the current latest core code and configuration. Is there a guide yet written for this? Originally we just removed `explorer.js` from the `server/boot` folder to secure production, now wondering how to do the same, but also enable it on other non-public hosts.

`server/` now lists a `component-config.js` file, as well as a `middleware.production.json` that we do not have. I tried to add these files (and updated server.js to the below) and `npm install loopback-component-explorer`, but I still can't get an explorer to mount.

`server/boot` now has a `root.js` and `authentication.js`, but we also still have `rest-api.js`. Does `root.js` take over from the more verbose `rest-api.js`?

The core code is now basically the same (also updated to latest with salita, so all package.json versions match—the only difference is the empty project `app.get('loopback-component-explorer')` returns something but in my modified project it's `undefined`.

**What am I missing?**

Our existing server.js:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot     = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname);

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
  });
};

// start the server if `$ node server.js`
if (require.main === module) {
  app.start();
}
```

server.js from a `slc loopback` scaffolding:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot     = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);

    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }

  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

Comment: Downvoting without commenting should not be allowed.

Comment: Downvoter could have asked you to explain more instead of downvoting. And yes, downvote without reason is irritating. Anyway, upvoting the question.